# aerospike JUNIT Record Constructor not working

Tags: java, junit, classcastexception, aerospike

I am writing aeropsike junit test cases for my test cases. For Storing aerospike bins, i am using ConcurrentHashMap.

```
// InMemory Map for storing AeroSpike Related Data...
ConcurrentMap<String, Bin[]> aerospike_keyBins = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Bin[]>();

// InMemory Map for storing AeroSpike Related Data...
ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> aerospike_keyGen = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Storing of bins and GenNumber related information is working perfectly fine.

But i am facing issues while getting record from map (Actually converting bins values from `Map` to Aerospike `Record`).

Here is the function which is expected to convert the same.

```
private Record binsToRecord(String stringKey, Bin... bins) {
    Map<String, Object> mapOfBins = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Bin bin : bins) {
        mapOfBins.put(bin.name, bin.value);
    }
    return new Record(mapOfBins, aerospike_keyGen.get(stringKey), 1);
}
```

While Calling `new Record` in that function i am getting following error message.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aerospike.client.Value$StringValue cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.aerospike.client.Record.getString(Record.java:66)
```

On Debugging this issue, i found that in `Record.class` of Aerospike,
following function is giving error.

```
/**
 * Get bin value as String.
 */
public String getString(String name) {
    return (String) getValue(name);
}
```

`getValue` is returning correct value but `(String) getValue(name)` throwing error.

Any clue about why am i getting this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Your binsToRecord method looks fine.

```
/**
 * Get bin value as String.
 */
public String getString(String name) {
    return (String) getValue(name);
}
```

Here in the Bin binValue is a StringValue object so you can't directly cast it to String.
try

```
(getValue(name)).toString()
// StringValue object provide toString() method.
```

Comment: thanks sudhanshu. I got the actual issues in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was while putting values to local hashmap.
I was pushing StringValues type of values in local hashmap Fixing that to put Standard String fixed the problem.

Here is the new binsToRecordfunction.

```
/*
 * Convert Bin Set to Record Object.
 */
private Record binsToRecord(String stringKey, Bin... bins) {
    Map<String, Object> mapOfBins = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Bin bin : bins) {
        if (bin.value instanceof Value.StringValue)
            mapOfBins.put(bin.name, bin.value.toString());
        else if (bin.value instanceof Value.LongValue)
            mapOfBins.put(bin.name, bin.value.toLong());
        else if (bin.value instanceof Value.DoubleValue)
            mapOfBins.put(bin.name, bin.value.toLong());

    }
    return (new Record(mapOfBins, aerospike_keyGen.get(stringKey), 1));
}
```